# How to split a string array based on dynamic entries of values?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I am trying to split an array of Strings (input obtained from console) now stored in String[] args

`host 9 7 1 router 5 8 11 lan 1 5 2 9`

Now args receives the values and stores them as

`args[0] = "host", 
args[1] = "9", 
args[2] = "7"` so on and so forth.

The values that come after strings "host", "router" and "lan" are generated dynamically, i.e. the no of values can change

e.g another instance can be

`host 0 4 3 9 router 4 9 2 lan 1 3 4 7`

For the above mentioned example I want to create a

`String[] hosts` that will store `0,4,3,9`
`String[] routers` that will store `4,9,2`
`String[] lans` that will store `1,3,4,7`

How can I do this?

Comment: With a loop. Or if you want to over engineer it, regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String in = "host 0 4 3 9 router 4 9 2 lan 1 3 4 7";

    List<String> storage = Arrays.asList(in.split(" "));

    boolean isHost = false;
    boolean isRouter = false;
    boolean isLan = false;

    List<String> hostList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> routerList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> lanList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(String val : storage){
        if("host".equals(val)){
            isHost = true;
            continue;
        }
        else if("router".equals(val)){
            isRouter = true;
            isHost = false; 
            continue;
        }
        else if("lan".equals(val)){
            isHost = false;
            isRouter = false;
            isLan = true;
            continue;
            }

        if(isHost){             
            hostList.add(val);
        }
        else if(isRouter){              
            routerList.add(val);
        }
        else if(isLan){             
            lanList.add(val);
        }
    }

    System.out.print("Host: "); System.out.println(hostList);
    System.out.print("Router: "); System.out.println(routerList);
    System.out.print("Lan: "); System.out.println(lanList);

}
```

Output:

```
Host: [9, 7, 1]
Router: [5, 8, 11]
Lan: [1, 5, 2, 9]
```